# Most efficient way to find iterators of 4 maximum values in const vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, constants, complexity-theory

I have to find 4 the biggest numbers in a const vector and return their positions. I want this code to have the best time and space complexity. My first idea is to copy this const vector into vector and bubble sort it 4 times. That gives me 4*N but i have to create a vector. Second idea is to put everything from this const vector into priority_queue. That gives me a N*log2(N) time complexity without creating another variables. The maximum of N is around 100.

Is there any other options to do it in the fastest and the least space-consuming way?

EDIT: It doesn't matter which one is the biggest, I just need to return position of this 4 items in the input vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this quite easily with an extra `vector`, and the `nth_element` algorithm, which is `O(n)` time:

```
std::vector<int> const v = ...;

// create a vector of elements with original indexes
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> res;

// populate the result vector
int k = 0;
for (int i : v)
  res.push_back({i,k++});

// find the maximum 4 elements
std::nth_element(res.begin(), res.begin() + 4, res.end(),
   [](auto const &a, auto const &b) { return a.first > b.first; });
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r9_7wp).

Note that this solution uses `O(n)` extra space. If `N` grows large, then this might not be the right approach for finding just `4` largest elements. It's still a good approach if you want the `M` largest elements, where `M` grows like `N`.

Comment: Great time efficiency at the expense of space O(N) instead of O(1).

Comment: True, if `N` were unbounded. 100 ints, on the other hand, is not a lot of space to be concerned about. Even twice that space would be worth it for a time speed up.

Comment: I am just pointing out the space/time trade-off for future reference. I like the solution as it is!

Answer (score 3):

O(n) solution

```
std::vector<int>::iterator max1 = v.begin(), max2 = v.begin(), max3 = v.begin(), max4 = v.begin();
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
    if((*max1) < (*it)) {
        max4 = max3;
        max3 = max2;
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = it;
    } else if((*max2) < (*it)) {
        max4 = max3;
        max3 = max2;
        max2 = it;
    } else if((*max3) < (*it)) {
        max4 = max3;
        max3 = it;
    } else if((*max4) < (*it)) {
        max4 = it;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: I'd however use `for(auto x : v)`... for `int`s using iterators or even references shouldn't IMO help in this case (to be sure one has to profile of course... modern CPUs and compilers are so complex that guessing quite often doesn't work).

Comment: Doesn't compile. A `vector<int>` doesn't contain `std::vector<int>::iterator`s. -1

Comment: Oh and the declarations on the first line have the opposite problem

Comment: My bad, sorry. Updated code. Now it works. some syntax errors.

Comment: Okey I see this is the best option for me, because N won't change and it's something that I thought at the very beggining but I got some syntax problems. My function takes &v as an imput and I can't enter v.begin() into max iterators. It might be silly question but how should i do that?

Comment: @Asachi `v->begin()` perhaps?

Comment: yes @kmdreko v -> begin() and v -> end() should work.

Comment: if `v` is a pointer to the vector, then `v->begin()`, and `v->end()` should work. I did try that and it works.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/8bvT3KX/1.png

That's what I see in my compiler @JugalRawlani :/

Comment: whenever you are declaring or defining a function, and one of the parameters needs to be a pointer, its not declared as `std::vector<int> &v`, its declared as `std::vector<int> *v`, and while call, we pass that specific argument as `&v`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a **heap** of size four. Then you iterate through the vector and update the heap accordingly.

Sample code using std heap methods and finding *minimum* values ([from here](https://github.com/gerbilvis/gerbil/blob/94f704447b5ce2dcd77019a641d96382dcb174a7/som/gensom.h#L219)) follows.

```
const std::vector<int> input;
const size_t n = 4;
std::vector<int> ret(n);
auto dfirst = ret.begin(), dlast = ret.end();

// initialize heap with infinity distances
std::fill(dfirst, dlast, 100000000000); // do better here

for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
{
    if (*it < *dfirst) {
        // remove max. value in heap
        std::pop_heap(dfirst, dlast); // add comparator as third arg

        // max element is now on position "back" and should be popped
        // instead we overwrite it directly with the new element
        *(dlast-1) = *it;
        std::push_heap(dfirst, dlast); // add comparator as third arg
    }
}
std::sort_heap(dfirst, dlast); // remove if not needed, or add comparator as third arg
return ret;
```

Adapt accordingly:

- Use a pair of index, value in the heap to keep track of positions which you like to return
- Use comparator that compares on value in the pair and establishes a desc. ordering

This is more generic than @Jugal Rawlani's solution if your number `n` might change/grow in the future. Otherwise his idea wins.

Comment: This isnt the most performant code you can write. But I think op should strongly consider this option as its going to be the easiest to extend and is still reasonably efficient

Answer (score 0):

read the 4 first elements into a vector of 4. sort this vector so that minimum of the 4 is in index 0.

loop on remaining items of the const vector, if current value > min, replace it and re-sort the 4 element vector

Comment: In other words, use a heap ;)